# ("id").val() not working with tr:subform tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, trinidad

I am using apache trinidad. I have used a tr:subform tag, inside that I have a few elements like datefields, commandbutton each has got a Id. Now I have a jquery function that uses ('#id').val() to get the fields.But it does not work.I can see that the id of the field is in the pattern "subformid:fieldid" .But in the jquery function it is not able to get the values through val() .Here is the snippet

```
<tr:subform id="subform1">
<tr:outputLabel for="to_Date" value="To Date"/>
            <tr:inputDate id="to_Date"   value="#{customer.toDate }" >

            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"  />
            </tr:inputDate>
<tr:commandButton text="Filter" action="#{bean.action }" id="filterId"  partialSubmit="true"></tr:commandButton>

</tr:subform>
```

Here the id of the date field becomes "subform1:to_Date" automatically.But when I use document.getElementById('subform1:to_Date') it returns null .Here is my jquery function

```
    $(document).ready( function() {

        $("#subform1:filterId").click(function(){
            alert('filterid clicked');
            var datePrsn = "";
            datePrsn = $("#subform1:to_Date").val();
            }
});
```

Comment: can you post a little of your code?

Comment: `document.getElementById('to_Date')` would work for me

Answer (score 1):

`<tr:subform>` is run in **server side**, the HTML present of it would be `<tr id="...">`. So you just need to see what is the id rendered by server code, then get element by the id only, like [@Pilot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434066/id-val-not-working-with-trsubform-tag#comment34116251_22434066) suggested, for example:

```
document.getElementById('to_Date')
```

FYI: http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_subform.html

### EDIT

Escape the colon in the jQuery selector using two backslashes (`\\:`):

```
$('#subform1\\:filterId');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Firebug (for Firefox), or use F12 for Chrome or IE and click the element that you want, with these tools you can see the exact name generated for the element.

If you have another element like a tr:form or tr:table the name will appear as formId:subFormId:elementId or tableId:0:elementId